# I don't want to allow linewise scrolling in textArea in noneditable mode

Tags: apache-flex

I don't want to allow linewise scrolling(means through arrow key) in textArea in noneditable mode

Answer (score 1):

Without having time to actually write the code, here's what I would do conceptually:

1. If your `TextArea` is not editable, add an `EventListener` that checks to see if the `TextArea` currently has focus. When the `TextArea` has the focus your `EventListener` should create another `EventListener` that looks for a keyboard event.
2. In your keyboard event `EventListener`, check to see if the key that was pressed was an arrow key. If it was an arrow key, trap the event and do nothing.
3. When the `TextArea` loses focus, remove the `EventListener` that checks for the arrow keys being pressed.

I hope this helps!

**Edit:**
When a key is pressed on the keyboard, it has a specific keyCode Flex can use to tell which key was pressed. The arrow keys are 37 - 40.

To take from an example (from the [Adobe Live Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_11.html)):

```
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    private function initApp():void {
        myTextArea.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler);
    }

    private function keyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40)
        {
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    }
  ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: No worries. If this helped answer your question, please mark it as an accepted answer so it might help others as well. :)

Comment: thanks for this answer.... 
i have used this solution but i want no operation on arrow key......

Comment: In the *Do Something* part of the example I used, try `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`. I edited my example to include that line. I hope it helps!

Comment: I have also tried event.stopImmediatePropagation(); but it is not working . After using your example, cursor event is capturing but cursor is moving.....

Comment: I think this may be a bubbling issue. I've edited my example again to put the `eventListener` on the `TextArea` instead of the application.